# How to automatically switch input language when focus and back on focus lost

Tags: wpf, behavior, attached-properties

I want to write either attached property or behavior for TextBox so that when focused input language changes automatically based on set property

can anyone provide me with sample code to achieve this?

Here is the code I have so far but I want to set and unset language based on textBox focus so when TextBox focus lost I want to switch to inputlanguage which was selected before this atached this class changed it

```
    public static class InputLanguageSwitch
{
    #region Dependency properties
    /// <summary>
    /// language to switch to when input got focus
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyboardLanguageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeyboardLanguage", typeof(string), typeof(Localization), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnKeyboardLanguageChanged));

    #endregion

    #region Dependency properties Get/Set methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Return selected keyboard language
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetKeyboardLanguage(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return d.GetValue(KeyboardLanguageProperty) as string;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set input language base on keyboard
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public static void SetKeyboardLanguage(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(KeyboardLanguageProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Even processing
    /// <summary>
    /// action to perform when input language changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">Dependency object</param>
    /// <param name="e">DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs</param>
    public static void OnKeyboardLanguageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is TextBoxBase)) return;
        var textBox = d as TextBoxBase;
        var language = FindKeyboardLanguage((string) e.NewValue);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) e.NewValue) | ReferenceEquals(language, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            //textBox.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus -= OnTextBoxPreviewGotKeyboardFocus;
            d.ClearValue(InputLanguageManager.InputLanguageProperty);
            d.ClearValue(InputLanguageManager.RestoreInputLanguageProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            //textBox.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus += OnTextBoxPreviewGotKeyboardFocus;
            d.SetValue(InputLanguageManager.InputLanguageProperty, language);
            d.SetValue(InputLanguageManager.RestoreInputLanguageProperty, true);
            InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = language;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Find and return keyboard language if one specified as an argument
    /// is installed on machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tag">language tag</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="CultureInfo"/> for requested language></returns>
    public static CultureInfo FindKeyboardLanguage(string tag)
    {
        CultureInfo result = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
        {
            if (InputLanguageManager.Current.AvailableInputLanguages != null)
                foreach (CultureInfo c in InputLanguageManager.Current.AvailableInputLanguages)
                {
                    if (c.IetfLanguageTag.ToUpper().StartsWith(tag.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        result = c;
                    }
                    if (c.IetfLanguageTag.ToUpper() == tag.ToUpper())
                    {
                        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
                    }
                }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it? Have you tried setting the language with `InputLanguageManager` class in the Textbox `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events?